# Magento 2 Catalog search result customize

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I am facing one issue in catalog search in `Magento 2.2.2`
I have one attribute called custom_name and value is like `'n12-n13-n15'`. This attribute is searchable and if  I search this in quick search then Magento consider it as a `separate value like 'n12' and 'n13' and 'n15'`.

Is there anyway so that I can prevent Magento to explode this string with `'-'`?

edit : 
Can I achieve this for specific(SKU) attribute?

Comment: change setting to full text search

Comment: Can you please guide me how can I do that ?

Comment: I have referred some website and found that Magento 2 has by default full-text search function its called Full-text MySQL search engine.

Comment: @DhavalSolanki, Did you find any solution?